# Best way to sort and rename files from osx command line

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a list of files I wish to sort by date and then rename them to file1, file2, filen, where file1 is the oldest and filen is the newest added.

Kind of like piping the sorted output of ls to mv but I would like to know what the best practices would be for this.

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this, but I would test it out on a COPY of your files in a directory on its own. If/when it works, remove the word `echo` in the third-to-last line because for the moment, it only shows what it would do, without doing anything:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while IFS=$'\n' read f; do
   # Get file creation date through mdls
   creation=$(mdls -raw -name kMDItemFSCreationDate "$f")

   # Convert that to seconds for sorting
   epoch=$(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z' "$creation" +%s)

   # And send on to "sort" along with the filename
   echo $epoch:$f
done < filelist.txt | sort | while IFS=":" read d f; do
   echo mv "$f" file$i
   ((i++))
done
```

It assumes your file list is stored in a file called `filelist.txt`